# OS X Automator: Automatically insert text into appearing text prompt

Tags: macos, applescript, vpn

I have purchased [Shimo](https://www.feingeist.io/shimo/) - a VPN client for Mac OS X - and so far am very satisfied with it.

However, I use the service of [VPNBook.com](https://www.vpnbook.com/) which provides free access to some of their VPN servers. The problem is that every 24 hours or so the password to all the free accounts change, the username remains the same.

Shimo offers an option to insert the username for each VPN connection so the only thing that has to be entered is the password.

I have an executable function that returns reads and returns the current password. So, if I run `vpnpw` into the terminal, it prints the current working password.

The whole thing looks like this:

[image: Returned VPN password]

My plan is now to implement a script that, when Shimo asks for the password, automatically calls `vpnpw` and inserts it into the prompt. Shimo offers triggers, for example running a shell script or an application when a connection is attempting to be established. So this should make things easier.

Here is a screenshot of how the prompt looks like (sorry for the German language):

[image: Password prompt]

What is the best way to do this? I thought about using Automator to run `vpnpw` whenever the prompt is being displayed. However, I am not experienced with Applescript or Automator in general. Help would be much appreciated because I would like to automate this whole process.

Just for reference, I have attached my script returning the current VPN password for VPNBook.com [under this link](http://pastebin.com/UaxR8zvb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this....

```
on run
    set thePwd to do shell script "vpnpw"
    set the clipboard to thePwd
end run
```

then I think you'll have to resort to GUI scripting

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using command down
end tell
```

You'll need to enable UI scripting in your system preferences before this will work. You can see how/where to do that [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/applescripts-ui-scripting-mac/)

All said and done, your entire script could look something like this...

```
on run
    set thePwd to do shell script "vpnpw"
    set the clipboard to thePwd

    tell application "Shimo" to activate -- You'll have to check this code, I don't have Shimo to know if this will work

    do shell script "sleep 1" -- just to allow time for shimo to become the front app before the paste

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using command down -- paste the clipboard
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Your solution works almost perfectly, thanks again for that. However, I learned that custom environmental executables - in this case `vpnpw` - can only be executed by `bash`, not by `sh`. But AppleScript's `do shell script` does use sh. Is there a way to solve this? In the best scenario, making all registered executables available for `sh`?

Comment: @kolja - Honestly, I've never run into that. Sounds like it's worthy of another post to the forum.